# Right side of a page being completely ignored by Inspect Element/Firebug despite CSS properties being in place for it

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I'm making a Tumblr theme for a friend of mine and I'm running into a very huge problem that's impeding me being able to do anything else. I've tried to seek help from other Tumblr coders and nobody has answered me, so I've come here (I've also searched on here and haven't found a thing similar to this).

I illustrated my problem recently in [this post on my Tumblr](http://guardianoftime.tumblr.com/post/44028536633/maybe-i-should-illustrate-my-problem-thats-probably) but to reiterate...

The theme I'm making for my friend is a two column theme with a header bar at the top. The header and right column of the theme are meant to be fixed in place so that only the left column moves when scrolling.

The left and right columns are floated left and right respectively and both have IDs with CSS and everything. I also have the header working properly in that it's fixed and moves with the page as it's scrolled. The problem, though, is that the right column is COMPLETELY unresponsive. The page acts like it doesn't even exist, actually, and therefore none of the CSS written for it renders at all.

The HTML for it shows up, of course, but when I select it when Inspecting Elements on the live preview I have, there are no inline styles listed for it whatsoever. It's very unusual and not a problem I have ever experienced and therefore know no solution to it.

[Here's the current WIP live preview I have if you want to look at it for yourself](http://promisemakertest.tumblr.com/) (the password is "Asbel" without quotes). I've added some colors in an attempt to find other issues, but you can find the right column by Inspecting.

I'm just really at a loss for what to do? I've done everything I could think of: took away the position property on it and the header (removing it from the header only moved it below the header but it still acted like it didn't exist), tried to add display properties with no results, took away the float, tried to move the column to other parts of the code and still encountered the problem......I've basically run out of options that I know of on what to do. I even tried a counter to float leakage that I'd learned about and it still did nothing.

I NEED the right column to work properly in order to continue working on this theme at all, so if anyone at all out there has any inkling of an idea as to what the problem might be, PLEASE HELP ME???? I would be eternally grateful to you.

If it helps at all, this is the sketch I made for this layout and what it's SUPPOSED to look like by the time I'm done with it (only with color and more to scale):

WELP, I was going to include that, but the site's not letting me. Sorry!

(Additionally, though it's not the pressing issue right now, I can't seem to get the tags to display the way I have them in the CSS. It was working properly at once time, but now it's not and I have no idea what happened or could've happened to make that suddenly happen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one closing curly brace ..

Line 72 on the `.photo img` selector

Comment: Aah, thank you! I hadn't noticed that ; A;. I went and added it in using style editor and that....appears to make the right column work? But not it's on the left and not the right......OTL

Comment: I did, sorry! Thank you for the help, I hate when I derp this badly in code OTL.